# COCOS 2dx setColor(Color3B::GREEN) is not working

Tags: android, c++11, cocos2d-x

when i am trying to publish ios game into android setColor(Color3B::GREEN) is not working,color of font not coming properly

```
l_answer = Label::createWithTTF(label_config,str_numberStr );
l_answer->setColor(Color3B::GREEN);
l_answer->enableOutline(Color4B(0,0,0,255),255);
l_answer->enableGlow(Color4B(0,0,0,225));
l_answer->setScale(0.0f);
```

Color of font not coming properly.

Comment: What does "not coming properly" mean?

Comment: actually i want that my label(font) color should come  dark green.but bydefault it coming shaded black.color of the font is not coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t set more than one effect on the label. Effects defined in `enum class LabelEffect` in `ccTypes.h` and they cancel each other. Now you can see only Glow effect, but if you swap `enableOutline()` `and enableGlow()`, you will see only Outline effect.
For example, for code

```
Label* lbSomeText = Label::createWithTTF("sometext", "fonts/junegull_rg.ttf", 100);
lbSomeText->setPosition(Vec2(winSize.width * 0.5f, winSize.height * 0.5f));
lbSomeText->setColor(230,110,180); // I set for more contrast with green
lbSomeText->enableGlow(Color4B(0,0,0,255));
lbSomeText->enableOutline(Color4B(0,255,0,255), 15);
this->addChild(lbSomeText);
```

result is:

[image: outline]

For code

```
...
lbSomeText->enableOutline(Color4B(0,255,0,255), 15);
lbSomeText->enableGlow(Color4B(0,0,0,255));
...
```

result is:

[image]

Next, if you want to see `GREEN` effect, you need set `Color4B(r, g, b, alpha)` to `Color4B(0, 255, 0, 255)`. Now you have `(0, 0, 0, 255)` and result is `BLACK` color. For example, here is result for `lbSomeText->enableGlow(Color4B(0,255,0,255));`

[image]

As you can see, there is little difference between green and black glowing, because you can’t to set width of glowing. So, if you need more glow, better way is make the sprite from label text in designer program like Photoshop and add more glow manually in this program.
I hope, I answered your question. Now you can choose which option suits you best.